# Adding Try and Catch to existing program

Tags: c#-4.0

Good Evening all,
            In a little of a pickle with a huge brain fart and could use a little help with something.  So i wrote this C# console app that uses Selenium to open a web page, logs in, does some stuff, then submit a form and logs off the site.  Now I have this in a for loop to do it 100 times.  Now very rarely it may hiccup and throws an exception cause page didn't load fast enough or something.  I thought it may be good to use a try/catch but once as the catch catches the exception, but I want it to redo that loop number that it is on and continue on.  So example, say if i am on iteration 66 of 100 and it throws an exception cause page didn't load fast enough or there was an error on the page for that link, i need it to catch it, log it, then restart at number 66 again.  Below is some of my original code and another section of what i have gotten it to.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            for (Int64 i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                DateTime time;
                time = DateTime.Now;
                StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\folder\file.txt", true);
                IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                tw.WriteLine("Staring test," + time);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://site.com");
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("username");
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("password");
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.ui-standard-button")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("page")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("page")).Click();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                //Do awesome stuff
                DateTime time1;
                time1 = DateTime.Now;
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.Parameters")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Logoff")).Click();
                driver.Quit();
                tw.WriteLine("Stopping Test Successfully," + time1);
                tw.Flush();
                tw.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         try
           {
            for (Int64 i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                DateTime time;
                time = DateTime.Now;
                StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\folder\file.txt", true);
                IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                tw.WriteLine("Staring test," + time);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://site.com");
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("username");
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("password");
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.ui-standard-button")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("page")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("page")).Click();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                //Do awesome stuff
                DateTime time1;
                time1 = DateTime.Now;
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.Parameters")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Logoff")).Click();
                driver.Quit();
                tw.WriteLine("Stopping Test Successfully," + time1);
                tw.Flush();
                tw.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
         catch(Exception e)
        {
            StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\folder\file.txt", true);
            tw.WriteLine("Problem happened.  Restarting test.  Exception is :" + e);
            //Line of code to restart test at number 66 which I don't know
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Where //Line of code to restart test at number 66 which I don't know  is where my knowledge ends and hopefully is where someone else is.  Any guidance you can give would be great and appreciated.

Comment: Hint: put try/catch inside the loop....

Comment: Just be careful you don't get yourself into an infinite loop if it keeps failing. If you know the explicit exception that is thrown for the timeout than you should catch that and let other hard failures through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrementing the counter when an exception is encountered should do it.

```
for (Int64 i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    try {
        //main code here
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //logging here
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This i tested along with a couple of other ones provided and this is actually working the best that I can see, but want to thank everyone for their thoughts and controbutions.  Thank you Very much Sticky *fist pump*....Now one other question I have is Firefox actually doesn't close (duh i didn't tell it to close in my catch).  Would you recommend that i open Firefox before my try and if catch happens then close?  Or would you recommend something else?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to figure out why it's failing, but if that's not an option I would convert it to a while loop with a try catch

```
    int i = 100;
    while(i > 0)
    {
      try
     {
     //Do your logic here 
       i--
     }
      catch
     {
         //Log failure
      }//Don't decrement in case of failure
    }
```

Comment: I just think a while loop is more clear/readable if it's not deterministic how many times the loop will execute

Comment: all the times i have seen it fail is cause my ISP decided to have a lat spike and it failed to load the page in time due to that.  I will give this a try though

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Int64 i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
{
  for (;;)
  {
     try
     {
       //code here
       break;
     }
     catch (Exception exc)
     {
       //log error
     }
  }
}
```